# How to expose kubernetes pod to outside IP?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a kubernetes file that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <some_name>
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
        - image: <some_image>
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: <some_name>
          env:
          - name: ES_HOST
            value: blahblah.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com
          - name: ES_PORT
            value: "443"
          - name: DATALOADER_QUEUE
            value: some_sqs_queue
          - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
            value: us-west-2
            ...<bunch of variable>
            limits: &main_limits
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 256Mi
            requests: *main_limits
```

If I wanted to expose this to the outside world traffic because say my application exposes app metrics using prometheus on a port.. how do I expose that port to the outside world?

my application has these two lines that starts an http server that needs to be exposed:

```
METRICS_PORT=9100
start_http_server(METRICS_PORT)
```

that's a prometheus server

Comment: none of the answers provided was useful?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit weird to expose Prom metrics outside the local network but that aside, you use a Service. Usually a LoadBalancer type but sometimes NodeIP in special situations. Check out [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for more info.

Comment: NodePort* just for clarification if she/he is looking at the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try the below sample

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
```

you should be able to access the hello service at http://HOST_IP:NODE_PORT

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to expose your application in Kubernetes.

Services could be used to expose internally, for others applications running in the same cluster (type: ClusterIP), externally binding a host port to your application node (type: NodePort) or loadbalancing the traffice between the nodes (type: LoadBalancer)

> **ClusterIP**: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default ServiceType.
>
> **NodePort**: Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting :.
>
> **LoadBalancer**: Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.

If you are using a **cloud provider**, you could use a service type **LoadBalancer**, then your service will get an external IP from your cloud provider and will be accessible publicly:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <<some name>>
spec:
  selector:
    app: my_app_name # << HERE
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Please note that for it works, you need to add a `selector` in your deployment file to service know for what pods redirect the requests. Like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <some_name>
spec:
  selector:
    app: my_app_name # <= SELECTOR HERE
  replicas: 1
  template:
 ...
```

To check if everything is ok, use the command below and check for `EXTERNAL-IP`:

`kubectl get svc <some_name>`

**References:**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#with-selectors

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer

Answer (score 0):

In general it's recommended to expose pods via services and not expose the pod directly considering the ephemerality of the pod. 
As mentioned above by KoopaKiller, the ways to expose a service include:

1. ClusterIP: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP making the Service only reachable from within the cluster. For your purpose, this will not suffice.
2. NodePort: Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port. For your purpose, you will be able to connect the NodePort Service from outside the cluster by connecting to the nodeport for your service.
3. LoadBalancer: Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer. This is a safer option to use at high scale, however, note certain load balancers cost a decent amount. You might want to take that into account before choosing.